# I'm making a chatbox. I have a div and input field inside of a div. I want them to resize in a particular way. How do I do this, preferably with css?

Tags: css

**I have the following HTML:**

```
<div id="chat">
    <div id="content"></div>
    &gt;
    <input id="field">
</div>
```

**And the following styles.css:**

```
#chat {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -o-border-radius:5px;
    -ms-border-radius:5px;
}

#content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
}

#field {
    width: 95%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);    
    color: white;
}
```

Which, when combined with my various bits of JS and node and so on, ends up looking like [**this**](http://i.imgur.com/9UEmbRi.png).

I'm going to be adding jQuery UI to this in order to make div #chat resizable by edge dragging. I want:

- div #chat to remain fixed to the bottom left corner of the window.
- input #field to maintain a constant height, and change width to fit the width of div #chat, keeping in mind the greater than symbol positioned to its left.
- div #content to be the same width as input #field and take up the remaining height.

Is this possible with pure CSS? If not, what's the cleanest way to do this? Thanks a bunch for the time and help, Reader. I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you really 'want' to ask them all? Have some jsfiddle will really help to see what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="chat">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <label for="field">&gt;</label>
    <input type="text" id="field" placeholder="enter"/>
</div>
```

add css

```
#field{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: This mostly solved my issue. The only remaining imperfection is that, at large widths (800ish), input #field doesn't stretch all of the way to the right side.

Is there any way to fix that?